# Booting linux kernel using a simple char driver as console?

Tags: linux-kernel, console, driver, boot

I'm trying to boot the linux kernel (v3.16.1) on a simulation model of a Sparc v8 processor for an academic project.

The simulation model consists of a cpu, memory, timer and a simple polling based output device. We've modified the kernel so that a bootloader is not necessary. We directly put the kernel image in memory, set up some necessary variables and jump into  kernel code. We have a rudimentary polling based output-device, and we've been able to direct output of printk to this device.

The kernel boots all the way up to the start of "/init". After this point no output is visible. Just before this point, there's a warning displayed : "Warning: unable to open an initial console." My filesystem image seems to be fine, and contains a /dev/console node (I checked this with Qemu).

My understanding is that while printk works fine (using an early console), user processes need a device node with a proper device driver to be set up. Printk works fine, so is there a way to see all writes by user processes to the console via printk ? There's an existing driver called "ttyprintk" which sends all writes to printk. I enabled it and tried using it by passing "console=ttyprintk" kernel argument, but this gives the same warning. The kernel is not able to open "/dev/console" for writing.

**My questions are :**

1. Can I write a simple character device driver and use it as my console ? Inside this driver I plan to send all writes to printk. Is this possible ?
2. How can I ask the kernel to use this as my console ? Would kernel argument "console = /dev/MyDriver" work ?
3. Is there a simpler way to have /init and other user processes use my rudimentary output device as a console ?

4.Is there some other reason that could be causing the "Warning: unable to open an initial console." message ?

Thanks for any hints. I am new to kernel programming.

-neha

Comment: have you ever read this thread?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437995/initramfs-built-into-custom-linux-kernel-is-not-running

Comment: @Chris Tsui: Yes. I tried the steps mentioned in the answer. I have checked with both static device tables (explicitly creating device nodes /dev/console, /dev/ttyS0 etc using mknod and putting them into initramfs) and devtmpfs. I'm got the same warning each time. I suspect it has something to do with not finding the device driver, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way the `/dev/console` driver works is to attach to some other tty device (or devices!), which is/are then used for the console.  The sysfs attribute `active` of the console device (try `/sys/class/tty/console/active`) will tell you what device the console is attached to at the moment.

The kernel also tends to log console changes:

```
[    0.186989] dw-apb-uart ffc02000.serial0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xffc02000 (irq = 194, base_baud = 6250000) is a 16550A
[    0.755529] console [ttyS0] enabled
```

In the above log, once the serial port device was created the kernel decided to use it as a console.  This refers to the binding of the device to the driver in the kernel, not the device node in /dev.  The latter does not matter here.  Also understand that the attachment of the console device to a tty happens in the kernel.  `/dev/console` is not a symlink to another device node.

The kernel has chosen ttyS0 because I told it to via the kernel command line, `console=ttyS0,115200n8`.  Without a console argument, the kernel uses the first console that registers with `register_console()`.

So the question here is how can one get /dev/ttyprintk to be attached to /dev/console.  And the answer appears to be you can't.

A work around might be to create a custom initramfs that changes the /dev/console device node from major 5 minor 1 to use minor 3, thus changing it into /dev/ttyprintk.  Or symlink to achieve the same thing.  This should get init to use ttyprintk as its stdin/stdout/stderr.

In your example, writing a tty/console driver for your output device would be the right way.  Make it the console and then the kernel sends printk there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The last line in your answer is exactly how I managed to get this to work. I wrote a simple tty/serial driver for the output device.